# Confirmation from user before updating a new version of application in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store, itunes

We already have our iOS application in the AppStore and we are about to release a new version of the iOS application. Is it possible for the users that while they update the new version we need a confirmation from the user like *"Are you sure you want to update the new version?"* Can we show this alert while the user update the version from iTunes directly. Guide me for the above scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Check the link [Happy](https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Harpy) or [iVersion](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iVersion). but you add this code in Already available version. or you add this code in your current version. it will affect next version of release only. sorry for poor english.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there's no such confirmation in standard iTunes upgrade flow. Unless you have programed a notification system in your old app to display this confirmtion in your app. looks like you didn't......

Answer (score 0):

from within the app (programatically) there is no control on the application's installation, hence the implementation you're looking for is not feasible.